# Spring Boot and JavaFX, using WeaverFX

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javafx

I've created an JavaFX program with FXML. I was asked to make it into a Spring Boot application. I found this website to help me through it using WeaverFX. 
https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/javafx-spring-boot/
I followed the tutorial step by step and looking through my code, I have everything the same. Yet I get an error.

```
 @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        FxWeaver fxWeaver = applicationContext.getBean(FxWeaver.class);
        Parent root = fxWeaver.loadView(MyController.class);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
```

```
2020-04-08 11:41:16.728  INFO 14512 --- [JavaFX-Launcher] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Started application in 1.239 seconds (JVM running for 2.077)
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myprogram.attempttwo.controller.MyController' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1126)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.getBean(FxWeaver.java:295)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.lambda$load$1(FxWeaver.java:381)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.load(FxWeaver.java:381)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.loadView(FxWeaver.java:184)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.loadView(FxWeaver.java:125)
    at net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxWeaver.loadView(FxWeaver.java:94)
    at com.myprogram.attempttwo.application.JavaFxApplication.start(JavaFxApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$3(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
```

It seems that its not using the 'loadView' but I don't know enough about Java to figure out why it is not. Or at least things to check.

***edit showing MyController.class per request

```
package com.myprogram.attempttwo.controller;

import com.myprogram.attempttwo.application.WeatherService;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import net.rgielen.fxweaver.core.FxmlView;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@FxmlView("main-stage.fxml")
public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private Label weatherLabel;
    private WeatherService weatherService;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(WeatherService weatherService) {
        this.weatherService = weatherService;
    }

    public void loadWeatherForecast(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        this.weatherLabel.setText(weatherService.getWeatherForecast());
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the controller class. Did you annotate it appropriately?

Comment: added the controller class, seems to be annotated appropriately

Comment: Yes, looks correct. Spring boot must not be finding it. Try adding `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={MyController.class})` to your Spring Boot Application class (in addition to the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation). If you get additional similar message for other classes, you can add comma-delimited classes inside the `{}` for that annotation. (The bottom line is that the tutorial, I think, assumes all classes are in the same package. I'm guessing by your package names that you have separated them out into different packages, which makes Spring Boot unable to find the controller class.)

Comment: unfortunately I still get the same error, I tried moving the package around to have all the classes in the same package but still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your project structure seems to cause the issue. I mean your main class is in the  `com.myprogram.attempttwo.application` package and your controller classes are in the `com.myprogram.attempttwo.controller` package.

Please make sure that your main `JavaFxApplication` is in the root package to get initialized all its beans. For example, you can rename your controller package with `com.myprogram.attempttwo.application.controller` so that your controllers will be under the main class.

Comment: I've moved things around, in and out of packages. I'll keep trying, the example I found has the exact same structure.

Comment: I hope you tried my instructions and understood them correctly :)

Comment: Still learning so much, everyday is a new adventure. I feel like I followed the instructions, but haven't gotten any luck.

Comment: If you can edit your post with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or link that you have done so far, maybe I can help you.